# Why does bluetooth device watcher find not available devices?

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth, windows-10

I use deviceWatcher on windows 10 to find available bluetooth (BLE) devices. Available devices are corretly found. DeviceWatcher also find devices that were found in recent searching, but they are not available now (not powered and out of range). They are also found after restart of my application. Does someone know what may cause it?

Device watcher initialization:

```
    private List<DeviceInformation> Devices = new List<DeviceInformation>();
    private DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher;

    private void StartBleDeviceWatcher()
    {
        string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable" };
        string aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices = "(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")";

        deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices, requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);

        deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
        deviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_Updated;

        Devices.Clear();
        deviceWatcher.Start();
    }

    private void DeviceWatcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfo)
    {

    }

    private void DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInfo)
    {
        Devices.Add(deviceInfo);
        comboBox_AddItem(comboBox_devices, " MAC: " + deviceInfo.Id.Substring(44) + " | Name: " + deviceInfo.Name);
    }
```

Comment: It's how window works. You have to hanle *remove* event to see which devices are not available. However, if device is paired it will be returned always as found and you have to check that the device is really available somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Remove event help me. Also adding Devices in update event was needed in my case.